# PrimeNg Upgrade - Button.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'float: left;'

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I just started upgrading a project to primeNg 8.1.1 and it seem in-line `style` tags on buttons are no longer supported...

I'm getting the following error in all my buttons which have `style='float:left`:

```
Button.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'float: left;'
    at KeyValueDiffers.find (core.js:28471)
    at NgStyleR2Impl.setNgStyle (common.js:5884)
    at NgStyle.set ngStyle [as ngStyle] (common.js:6161)
    at updateProp (core.js:32189)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31867)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (Button.html:2)
```

this works fine on the previous version 8.0.3

I tried a few different formats for the in-line styling but still had no luck

this is the usual tag causing the issue:

```
<p-button (onClick)="clickRefresh()"
          icon="pi pi-refresh"
          label="Refresh"
          style="float: left;"
          styleClass="ui-button-secondary"
></p-button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you must change string to objects，I think this is a break change.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/b774ab2a5811b223c49dcef55ba84bcbcfa09579

```html
<p-button (onClick)="clickRefresh()"
          icon="pi pi-refresh"
          label="Refresh"
          [style]="{float: 'left'}"
          styleClass="ui-button-secondary"
></p-button>
```